# Alexa skill - How to store more than 1 word as slot value

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I currently say - My name is John Smith.

I have my intent mapped as --> My name is {input}

However, Alexa only catches the last word ( Smith in this case). I want the input value to be 'John Smith' and not just 'Smith'.

```
name = intent["slots"]["input"]["value"]
print("Slot value is " + name)
speech_output = str(name) + " is what you spoke"
```

How can I achieve this using a single slot?

Comment: Could you share your slot definition, specifically which slot values you added in your skill interaction. If all slot values are single words, Alexa would only assign a single word to a slot. Try adding "John Smith" as an acceptable slot value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custome slot like below,

"slots": [ { "name": "FirstName", "type": "AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME" }, { "name": "LastName", "type": "SEARCHTEXT" } ]

Instead of AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME you can use custom slot as well.

Please refer below link,

https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/32213/alexa-slot-definition-for-firstlast-name.html